# Crystal Report takes long time to load every time in VS2010

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I am working in a window project in asp.net4.0. I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have create an Invoice report in Crystal Report . Problem is that It takes1 minute to load every time. I have searched on google and also unchecked the option "Save Data in Report". But it does not effect report loading time.

So please help me. provide any idea or solution of my problem...

Comment: How long does the underlying stored procedure/query take? How many pages does it render? Have you checked "No Printer (optimized for screen display)" under Page setup?

Comment: I have checked in coding by putting Break Points. So I found that when i write following line then it takes 50 seconds to load report objReport.SetDataSource(dtInvoiceDetail);

Comment: How many rows are in the datatable?

Comment: Actually I found that i have created a crystal report in my old machine that is working fine in that machine. in That machine that takes only 4-5 seconds but now i have changed My Machine and it takes 50 seconds. But When I have redesign new report in my new machine then it takes only 2-3 second to load. So I am searching that what is real solution for this problem. may be u can understand this scenario..

Comment: Did you check the printer settings for the old report?

Comment: yes i have set all setting of new report as  equal to old reports. As I have said a report created on new machine takes 2-3 seconds and old report of old machine take 50 seconds. please look in to this issue...

Answer (score 17):

Hi I have found the solution to my Problem:

Open Crystal Report in Design Mode then Goes To Properties of Crystal Report

Crystal Report ->  Design -> Page Set Up -> Check **"No Printer"** property.

and then My Report Take 2-3 seconds to load every time on my machine as well as in client machine.

Comment: Thanks, it help me. By default it saves current printer and when deployed it is searching for that printer which takes around 30 seconds after setting no printer it is working very fast.

Comment: Had this problem for a long time and thanks for this and it solved the issue. :)

Comment: Crystal report loads the page setting according to selected printer preference. if we have applied any page settings in printer preference then it would be taken first for the report document. This process takes some times.

Answer (score 1):

Open Crystal Report in Design Mode then Goes To Properties of Crystal Report

> Crystal Report -> Design -> Page Set Up -> Check "No Printer" property.

and then My Report Take 2-3 seconds to load every time on my machine as well as in client machine.

I support for the above answer, really it shows a lot of difference. 
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Project > click (Winform)properties... > click Build and select platform target choose x86 and

Answer (score 0):

When Loading home page or some page just run empty Crystel Report(only solution for initial start slow), I think that time take ready for some DLL files.

code examples

```
reports.ReportSource = null;
this.Close();
```

hope this will help you!

Answer (score -1):

I have solution for this. (this works for me!)

1. From the report > right click> page setup > uncheck "no printer" for optimization.

   2. If it is still slow, go to Start > Devices and Printers. Remove all the printers that are connected to the network. You won't need printers in developing crystal reports unless you want to print the report.